# Google users API returning email address other than the one just used to login by user

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Just wondering whether there are any circumstances under which the Google Users API would return an email address other than the email address that the user JUST USED to login.

I am debugging an inherited Google App Engine website and have isolated it to this:

```
self.google_user = users.get_current_user()
email = self.google_user.email()
```

This code isn't returning the email address that the user just used to login via Google. It's returning a different email address.. a Gmail address in this case.

Has anyone have experienced a problem like this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is as follows - the Google Users API only returns the PRIMARY email address of the Google account. So the user can sign in to our app through a Google Account associated with their secondary email address but we'll only get the primary email address from the API. So it appears that we got given a different email address to the one the user just used to sign in with.

Actually we got given the primary address of the Google account they just used their secondary email address to sign in with (mind bending).

Answer (score 1):

Email addresses can change, perhaps it's returning their original address for some reason.

You might want to use the unique ID which will never change instead:

> You probably want to store the user ID (and perhaps the last-seen mail address to communicate with the user by mail). The user ID stable; you can use it in a key name or as a string property.
>
> You probably don't want to store a UserProperty. Within the datastore,
>   the value is equal to the email address plus the user's unique ID. If
>   a user changes their email address and you compare their old, stored
>   User to the new User, they won't match.
>
> Both the db and NDB libraries have UserProperty property types so that applications can store user values. However, since these values
>   become invalid when users change email address, most applications have
>   no good use for this feature.

[User Objects](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/userobjects)

Comment: the email address hasn't changed. they are logged into an account with email address A. But user.email() returns email address B.

Comment: I believe gmail and googlemail are interchangeable, e.g. Paul@gmail.com and Paul@googlemail.com. More info on that here, http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=159001 perhaps it's linked. Other then that, not sure!